# No windows 7 option in grub

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

Gys I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop which had windows 7 previously.

After installing ubuntu their was no option for boot selection and ubuntu 12.04 was getting booted automatically. I used boot repair to fix this problem, but now grub shows only options to boot into ubuntu. 
Here is the log from boot repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1633565/

Comment: Maybe you find `Windows 7 loader locacted on dev/xyz` msg?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which boot manager is your preference, windows or Ubuntu.

If you want windows to manage the boot menu, it wouldn't recognize Ubuntu directly without a 3rd party boot manager like [easyBCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD).
 If you want Ubuntu to manager the boot menu, you need to load [grub2](http://fitusv.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/fixing-reinstalling-grub-grub2/). or you can repair your windows boot manager from the windows 7 install disk in repair mode.